# Disabling interpolation in SSRS 2012 line charts

Tags: reporting-services, graph, linechart

I have a chart where the x axis is comprised of dates. I give the chart data rows, with each row corresponding to a unique date, but occasionally dates are missing. Currently, the line chart's series just connects the existing points with a straight line. What I want is for the line to stop before non-existing datapoints such that the missing points are obvious.

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would customize the Empty Points properties for that series, e.g. setting the Empty Points / Color property to "No Color".

For more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207051.aspx

Comment: Right, I tried that. The problem is that the chart doesn't know the row is missing because the entire row is gone, not just the data within the row.

Comment: You probably need to go back to the Dataset and add a right join to a Calendar/Date Dimension style table to provide rows with no series values.